# How to find a bijection from the set $Hom(G_1\times G_2, G_3\times G_4 )$ to the cartesian product of four Hom sets?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose that $G_1, G_2, G_3, G_4$ be groups and consider $Hom(A, B)$ as collection of group homomorphisms from the group $A$ to the group $B$. We know that in general it is not a group but a set.

I know that there is a bijection from the set  $Hom(G_1\times G_2, G_3\times G_4 )$ to the set $Hom(G_1, G_3)\times Hom(G_1, G_4)\times Hom(G_2, G_3)\times Hom(G_2, G_4)$. I have come to know from my seniors that its easy to prove this result using module theory or some thing like which I have zero knowledge.

But I want to establish this using simple elementary set theoratic approach. I mean is it possible to construct any explicit bijection here using elementary group theory only ? I am confused if my question is correct or not  and if correct, then how to complete it ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The result is not correct. It fails even for $\operatorname{Hom}(G_1\times G_2,G_3)$ if you take for example $G_1 = G_2 = C_2$ and $G_3 = S_3$. There are $4$ homs from each copy into $S_3$, but not $16$ homs from their product.

Comment: Are the groups commutative?

Comment: Ohh My god. This is not true in general ? I thought it is true for arbitrary groups. :-(

Comment: @Bernard no. I am just considering arbitrary groups. Is commutativeness important here sir ?

Comment: The problem with your question is that if you have commutative groups, you do have an isomorphism. However $G_1\times G_2$ should be the coproduct, which happens to be the same as the direct product in the case of commutative groups, but it is no more true for general groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result isn't correct.

We do have $\text{Hom}(A, B \times C) \cong \text{Hom}(A, B) \times \text{Hom}(A, C)$ by the following isomorphism:

$$\phi: f \mapsto (\pi_1 \circ f, \pi_2 \circ f)$$

where $\pi_1 : B \times C \to B$ is the projection onto the first coordinate, and $\pi_2: B \times C \to C$ onto the second. You can check that this is an isomorphism.

Therefore, $$\text{Hom}(G_1 \times G_2, G_3 \times G_4) \cong \text{Hom}(G_1 \times G_2, G_3) \times \text{Hom}(G_1 \times G_2, G_4)$$

However, we can't necessarily do better: $\text{Hom}(G_1 \times G_2, G_3)$ is not necessarily $\text{Hom}(G_1, G_3) \times \text{Hom}(G_2, G_3)$. I see that Tobias Kildetoft's given the example $G_1 = G_2 = C_2$ and $G_3 = S_3$ in the comments.